# Detect if component is being 'attached' to server-rendered markup?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm server-side rendering a redux-powered react app. Everything working well on that front. I attach 'loader' methods that return promises to the route components and run them on the server before rendering. On the client, the loaders get called in `componentDidMount`.

What I'd like to do, is NOT call the loaders in `componentDidMount` if we just mounted to server-side markup. In all other cases the loaders should run.

I'm not sure how to detect if this is the case. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can track a single boolean on state for whether the app has rendered at least once. `ReactDOM.render` accepts a third callback function that you can use to trigger when the initial render is complete. I have something like this in my code:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  (<Provider store={store}>
    <App>
  </Provider>),
  document.getElementById('root'),
  () => store.dispatch(initialRender)
)
```

You can check that state in your `componentDidMount` methods to know if they should run or not.

Comment: Thanks @TimDorr! Worked like a charm. Some notes for those facing a similar task (in a redux app):

- Added window.__SERVER_SIDE_RENDERED__ = true
- Added an action constant/creator for INITIAL_RENDER
- Added a reducer call 'app' with a property called 'rendered' (default: false)
- In my loader decorator (which has the componentDidMount), I only run my loader if rendered is true OR the page was not rendered by the server (so that if I disable SSR, the loaders will run)